# Unable to create correctly shaped tuple from ((1, 1), (1, 1))

Tags: python, numpy

I used **Numpy** to pad an array

```
np.pad(img, ((row,row), (col,col)), mode)
```

but got the **error:**

```
Unable to create a correctly shaped tuple from ((1, 1), (1, 1))
```

However, when I generate an array with ones with **the same shape** *the error is **gone***!

I checked the size and type of image, there is nothing different to the generated one, what should I do!

Comment: is the img `rgb`? because you'll have shape*3 depth for that.

Comment: it's black and white, not rgb. But I don't know if there is a certain rgb mode or not for that

Comment: sorry, I printed the shape of image. it's (256,256,4). does that means it's rgb?

Comment: What are you passing in for `mode`?

Comment: It means it's `rgba`. `a` for transparency. In this case, you can separate your img into 4 slices and then do the same for each before assembling them back.

Comment: Thank you Rocky Li! 老哥你是中国人么？

Comment: 1。welcome to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys! Thanks for your help!
I found that the shape of image is (256,256,4), I think I mistook the black and white picture as a none rgb format picture.
I solved this problem after converting it to the right format

This is the first time I asked a question on stack overflow and it's amazing that there are kind people like you to help me solve my problem! Thanks again!